# Transfer data from function to variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to transfer data from function to variable, but I am get an error.

```
DECLARE @KullaniciID int

SET @KullaniciID = SELECT GetActivePersonelID
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'

Function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[F15_GetActivePersonelID]
   (@P int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @KullaniciID int

    SET @KullaniciID = (SELECT KullaniciID FROM IT15_Kullanicilar  
                        WHERE KullaniciKodu = dbo.F15_GetKullaniciConn ())

    RETURN (SELECT MAX(PersonelID) FROM IT01_Personel  
            WHERE KullaniciID = @KullaniciID)
END
```

Comment: `SELECT` can't be used after a `=` operator. You would either need to use a subquery, or use a `SELECT` instead of `SET` initially.

Comment: I can not use as set @KullaniciID = GetActivePersonelID . Error is Invalid column name 'GetActivePersonelID'.

Comment: Functions have parenthesis (`()`) afterwards, @EmreYıldırım . `F15_GetActivePersonelID` on it's own would reference a column, not a function, just like `SELECT GETDATE FROM dbo.MyTable` would *actually* return the value of a column (foolishly) named `GETDATE` from the table `MyTable`, *not* the the current date and time returned from the function `GETDATE()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1, via SET:

```
SET @KullaniciID = (SELECT [dbo].[F15_GetActivePersonelID](123))
```

Option 2, using inline syntax:

```
SELECT @KullaniciID = [dbo].[F15_GetActivePersonelID](123)
```

I would recommend avoid using scalar functions in SQL Server due to known problems with performance and scaling.
There are some improvements in SQL Server 2019 though.